# Using the window object for session storage instead of AmplifyJS store

Tags: javascript, session-storage, amplifyjs

I'm using AmplifyJS Store. I think it's a good wrapper for persistent storage. I've been using it in a JQuery plugin and it works pretty well.

Lately though, I've been wondering if I can just do the same thing using a namespace variable in the `window` object?!

AmplifyJS Store + JSON2.js (required for data serialization) costs me 22Kb (8Kb minified) of file size alone, not to mention the additional supporting code I've had to create around it. Also, I'm using only sessionStorage (i.e. I have no need for persistence after the browser window closes, only while the window is active).

So, is there really any major reason I can't use the `window` object instead of AmplifyJS Store for my specific circumstance?! I've thought about the `expiry` feature but I can easily build in same functionality in a few lines of code.

Thanks.

Comment: Anything stored on window is not persistent. You reload the page or follow a link, you lose all data.

Comment: @bfavaretto Thanks. Can you please post that as an answer?! Cheers.

Comment: Since another user already did that, I'm upvoting his answer instead.

Comment: @bfavaretto Ok. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are actually trying to save persistent data (data that is still there if the page reloads or the user navigates away), storing it on the window object is not an option.  The data won't be there when you check for it later.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I've really taken AmplifyJS Store for granted #BigTime lol. Maybe I'm trying to over-optimize.

Answer (score 3):

HTML5 localStorage in window object by itslef has a very simple api:

```
 var valueOfName = window.localStorage.getItem("name");
 window.localStorage.setItem("name", "value");
```

you can even omit global window object:

```
 var valueOfName = localStorage.getItem("name");
 localStorage.setItem("name", "val");
```

moreover you can apply array-style notation:

```
 var valueOfName = localStorage["name"];
 localStorage["name"] = "value";
```

that is it! And it doesn't have an expire date, URL strings or other complications in its API which took place in elder cookies-approach. All what AmplifyJs provides (as I can see) is a support for older browsers (who were using cookies) by givin' you the same API as original localStorage does.

In other words if you are not targeted on Netscape Navigator, Mosaic and IE 7 you can forget about using of AmplifyJS and apply native localStorage API.

However despite an approach, you should never rely on client-side persistance for sure, because it is totally dependent from local browser (client could simply clear cache, reinstall something or sign-in from other computer) - use server-side databases and similiar technologies for saving user's info.

Comment: Thanks. AmplifyJS Store also allows you to set the StorageType e.g. localStorage, sessionStorage, etc. In my particular case, I'm using sessionStorage exclusively. I have built in my own logic to use `sessionStorage` as default, or if this is not available, rely on the wisdom of AmplifyJS Store. I'm not storing any critical user data, just data the plugin needs to function while the web page is active.

Comment: BTW diff between local&session storages (according to spec) is a time when it is purged: for local it remains until you remove an item with either localStorage.removeItem(key) or delete localStorage['key'] or rewrites with a new value, but  sessionStorage is erased each time an user closes the browser's window (this is why I mostly prefer localStorage amon session - you can reload you PC for updates, restart browser and go back where you've been with the app). IMO it is always better to control time of erasure by yourself: e.g. cleaning your localStorage vars after log-out action.

Comment: Yes I understand the difference. I'm using sessionStorage because it's the best storageType for my application (no need for persistence after the user's session), plus it allows my application to function in a multi-browser-tab fashion without any issues